# Error when trying to resize Content Add-in in Excel Online when spreadsheet has more then one sheet

Tags: excel, office-js

Issue is happening for any Content app in Excel Online only when more than one sheet is present in the document. Reproducible in Internet Explorer v. 11 and Chrome v. 46.
 
Steps to reproduce: 
 1. Create new Excel document 
 2. Add new Sheet 
 3. Add any Content Add-in (f.e. 'Bubbles') 
 4. Try to move or resize Add-in 
Result: 'Sorry, something went wrong' error message is shown.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for posting this question. This is an issue we are aware of and we are working on a fix as soon as possible.

While we are working on this fix, one workaround is to open Excel on Excel Desktop, resize the content add-in and save the workbook.

Sorry for any inconvenience.

Thanks,
Sky

Comment: This issue should be fixed now:)